# protobuf-net serialization of primitive type arrays

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a simple array of integers using protobuf-net. However it seems that the .NET BinaryFormatter is performing better than the protobuf-net which is not what I would have expected. Here is the code that I am using to test the performance:

```
[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
public struct Vector3Double {
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public double x;
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public double y;
  [ProtoMember(3)]
  public double z;
}

public static void TestSerialization() {
  var v3ds = new Vector3Double[512 * 512];
  var ints = new int[512 * 512];
  for (var i = 0; i < v3ds.Length; i++) {
    v3ds[i].x = i;
    v3ds[i].y = i;
    v3ds[i].z = i;
  }
  var tmpFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

  System.Console.WriteLine("BinaryFormatter");
  System.Console.WriteLine("---------------");
  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of Vector3Double (serialization): ");
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    bf.Serialize(fs, v3ds);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of Vector3Double (deserialization): ");
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var des = bf.Deserialize(fs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine();
  System.Console.WriteLine("ProtoBuf Serializer");
  System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of Vector3Double (serialization): ");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, v3ds);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of Vector3Double (deserialization): ");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var des = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Vector3Double[]>(fs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine("BinaryFormatter");
  System.Console.WriteLine("---------------");
  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of int (serialization): ");
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    bf.Serialize(fs, ints);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of int (deserialization): ");
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var des = bf.Deserialize(fs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine();
  System.Console.WriteLine("ProtoBuf Serializer");
  System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of int (serialization): ");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, ints);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(tmpFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) {
    System.Console.Write("Array of int (deserialization): ");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var des = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<int[]>(fs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }
}
```

And these are the time results I get (all times in ms):

```
BinaryFormatter
---------------
Array of Vector3Double (serialization): 401
Array of Vector3Double (deserialization): 1266

ProtoBuf Serializer
-------------------
Array of Vector3Double (serialization): 206
Array of Vector3Double (deserialization): 186

BinaryFormatter
---------------
Array of int (serialization): 2
Array of int (deserialization): 1

ProtoBuf Serializer
-------------------
Array of int (serialization): 57
Array of int (deserialization): 60
```

So the BinaryFormatter serializes/deserializes an array of integers in approximately 1 to 2 ms, while the protobuf-net serializer/deserializer is taking 57 to 60 ms. Is there something wrong that I am doing in the code above? Or is protobuf-net not suitable for primitive arrays?

**Update 2016/04/29**

I did a little debugging of the protobuf-net-r668 source code and it seems that the array is written to the output stream one item at a time (inside TrySerializeAuxiliaryType in TypeModel.cs). Is it somehow possible to specify that the array should be written to the output stream all in one go? Or should I modify the source code to serialize/deserialize arrays for my usage scenario?